# Does anyone knows where can I find the phase diagram of oxygen free copper (OFC or OFHC)?

Tags: resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry, plasma-physics, phase-diagram

I am having problems with a niobium deposition I made on a substrate. I increased the temperature to 500 degrees celsius and in theory the film should have a better quality. However this wasn't the result and I am just trying to understand why.

Comment: Better quality in what way? What happened that you didn't expect? Oxygen free copper is, well, fairly pure copper, so should behave like copper (except it is vacuum compatible). Cu (fcc) and Nb (bcc) have very low solubility in each other, and have no intermediate phases.